# postgres connect as different user

Tags: postgresql

New to postgres. Till now I used mysql and whenever I needed to login I did this:

```
mysql -u root -p
```

which then prompted me to provide password for user `root`

But postgres feels a lot different than that. After installation I created a new user like this:

```
create user root with password 'something';
create database test;
grant all privileges on database test to root;
```

Now when I use pgadmin4 I get a prompt to enter my `sudo` password. Even when I try to connect to database via terminal using:

```
sudo -i -u postgres
```

It asks me for my `sudo` password.

How can I login via different user?

`lsb_release -a` gives:

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 21.10
Release:    21.10
Codename:   impish
```

Comment: added OS and release info

Answer (score 2):

Generally one would use the `psql` command when connecting to a PostgreSQL database, and the `-U` option will allow you to specify which username you would like to connect with:

```
psql -U {username}
```

As an aside ...

The use of `root` as a username is generally "bad form" and strongly discouraged in most database and development circles, as it's an obvious attack target – even for locally-installed instances that are not exposed to the Internet. Instead people generally recommend creating accounts for applications that are limited to single databases or accounts for people that are limited to a few. Administrators, of course, would have access to all, but with a unique username.

If you need to connect to PostgreSQL with the default `postgres` account, you can do so like this:

```
sudo –i –u postgres psql
```

Comment: So basically create different users for different databases and provide access to all resource to the admin.

But not to use the name `root`?

I can create different users and provide them permission to different dbs with the command:


`create user root with password 'something';`

But is the process same for creating a new admin and give him permission to all?
Can you provide some reference to it? thanks